# What is the path set for OpenSSL:X509::Store#set_default_paths method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I am doing this:

```
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.set_defaults_path
```

The documentation for this method is given in [OpenSSL::X509::Store](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Store.html).

From where does the certificate store object read the certificates? I perused the source code for the definition of set_default_paths but was not able to find one.

One theory is that the default paths may be the same as the ones given by 
`$ openssl version -a` 
But that theory fails even when you try to verify signed certificates against the certificate chain at your system root_ca_path.

Comment: Possibly related: [Can't verify CA certificate unless CApath or CAfile used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22304564) and [Which is the openssldir?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24959340)

Comment: Not really. This is specific to the Ruby DSL and how it interacts with OpenSSL.